# How do I send python lists to a bottle server?

Tags: python, bottle

I have a python file which has 4 python lists that gets basic information (ip, host, mac, signal) from devices connected to a rpi hotspot. I would like to send those lists from the Rpi to a bottle server constantly because that information can change over time (device disconnects, changes its signal ...). And finally, print that information on an HTML. How can I constantly send information in a simple way? Websockets? Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could setup a cron job on your RPI hotspot which periodically executes a curl command with the contents of the python lists as JSON. You mention "python lists" in your question, if you are just storing the data in a .py file then I would suggest writing it to another format like json instead.

Send the data from RPI device every minute

```
# 1 0 0 0 0 curl -vX POST http://example.com/api/v1/devices -d @devices.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Then in your bottle file have a method that receives the data POST and another that can display the data GET. The example just writes the received data to a json file on the server

```
from bottle import route, run
import json

@route('/api/v1/devices', method='GET')
def index(name):
    with open('data.json') as f:  
        return json.load(f)


@route('/api/v1/devices', method='POST')
def index(name):
    req_data = request.json
    with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
        data = json.load(f.read())
        # output = {**data, **req_data} # merge dicts
        output = data + req_data # merge lists
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(output)
        f.truncate()
    return {success: True}

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Note: I didn't test this code it is to give you and idea of how you might accomplish your request.

Comment: I don't understand why in curl you use @ device.json, in the get bit you used data.txt and in the post you used devices.json. Shouldn't there be the same? Apart from that, the code shows an 404 error on the browser. How am I supposed to run it? What I'm doing is run the server and after I run the curl command from the rpi but it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: fixed the naming inconsistency of the local files. the file sent with curl should not be the same as the one on the server storing the data. This is just meant as an example of how you can do it.